# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, token

Alright , I have a little problem with my form , I tried many ways all didn't work 
When I click on SEND it gives me this error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

Okay I got this , I put `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

under the  `<form action="" method="post" class="landing-form">`

Then I got this error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
```

this is my form code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>landin page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{asset('js/class.FormValidation.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{asset('js/landin_validation.js')}}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset ('js/style.css')}}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header-content">Company Logo Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Advertising Header Goes Here!</h1>
        <p>
          There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,<br/> 
          but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, <br/> 
          or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. <br/> 
          If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, <br/> 
          you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. <br/> 
          All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, <br/> 
          making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, <br/> 
          combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. <br/> 
          The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour,<br/>  
          or non-characteristic words etc.
        </p>
        <div class="form-wrapper">
          <form action="" method="post" class="landing-form">    
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <label>Fill your details here - </label><br/><br/>
            <input placeholder="Full name:" type="text" name="name" class="field-name" />
            <input placeholder="Email:" type="text" name="email" class="field-email" />
            <input placeholder="Phone Number:" type="text" name="phone" class="field-phone" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">2014 &copy; My Compay Name</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

also this is my class.FormValidation.js

```
function FormValidation(){

  this.nameReg = [
    /^([a-zA-Z\s]+){2,255}$/
  ];

  this.emailReg = [
    /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/
  ];

  this.phoneReg = [
    /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i,
    /^[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}$/i,
    /^\([0-9]{3}\)-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i,
    /^[0-9]{9,10}$/i
  ];

  this.testName = function( nameInput ){

    return this.inputCheck(this.nameReg, nameInput);

  };

  this.testEmail = function( emailInput ){

    return this.inputCheck(this.emailReg, emailInput);

  };

  this.testPhone = function( phoneInput ){

    return this.inputCheck(this.phoneReg, phoneInput);

  };

  this.inputCheck = function( regArray, inputData ){

    var valid = false;

    $.each( regArray, function( key, val ){

      if( val.test( inputData ) ){

        valid = true;

      }

    });

    return valid;

  };

}
```

this is the routes :

```
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');
```

and this is the pagescontroller :

```
public function contact(){

    self::$data['title'] = 'Contact us';
    return view('content.contact',self::$data);
}
```

I really hope you help me , thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your routes.php file?

Comment: Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');

Comment: you need to create a post route that points to a controller method that processes the form. Something like `Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@processContact')` with a corresponding `processContact` method on your controller.

Comment: thanks , but I still need the get for getting the page itself , and then the post for sending the form , but I want it in js validation (post) how can I do that ?

Comment: Setup a javascript event listener for the form submit event. Run your validation and if it validates, proceed with the submit, otherwise prevent the submit and display the errors.

Comment: I didn't get you , I tried to make something like this 

    public function postContact(ContactValidation $request) {

    }

Comment: so if the contactvalidation returns true it sends but this works for php

Comment: I can do something like this do you mean ? 

element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    alert ("Hello World!");
}

but I cant put this in the post validation how can I do that ?

Comment: yes. it just goes in a script tag at the bottom of the html page that contains your form.

Comment: In your html code above labeled "this is my form code", you need to add your event listener at the bottom, before the closing `html` tag, within a script tag.

Comment: I got it , but look , I have a file that gives error with the ajax (which sends to form_handler.php) file

Comment: also another php file which is the validation

Comment: To be honest, there is too much going on here to figure out what is going on and how to fix the issue on this forum. I would recommend you find someone local who can give you a hand or try to score a video chat with someone so they can see your files. Check twitter or airpair to try to find someone that can help via a video call.

Comment: public function postContact() {
      return view('content.contact',self::$data);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no available route for the POST request to your contact route. As you said:

`Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');`

Is the route to your form, but Laravel can't validate the GET-request with the POST-request you are sending from your form. So, you need a second route (and method) to handle the POST request:

`Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@postContact');`

You'd still need a postContact() method on your PagesController to handle the post request.

P.s. you can also use this:

`{!! csrf_field() !!}`

This adds the HTML code for the token field to your form without you having to type anything of a hidden field.

---

P.S. you can Also use this:

`Route::any('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');`

But that would require you doing the logic (seperating the POST from the GET request) in your contact() method.

Comment: Thanks a alot , but when I do it in this way , I don't get the landing page
(empty page) so I have to do getContact with return view and the postContact should be with a validation , but my validation in js file so how can I do that ?

Comment: Your formValidation function should return true when submitting the post and then do the POST requests to the same URL. Even if you are validating with javascript I'd strongly suggest you to still do validation in the PHP code. Copying your page without the JS validation, I could simply inject all kinds of values in your database by bypassing the JS

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend , helped .